# Send Ajaxcall to server with Arduino

Tags: javascript, ajax, arduino

I'am creating a project for which I get data from an force sensing resistor into my Arduino. Now I want to send the data from the force sensing resistor to my server trough an ajaxcall. How do I peform an ajaxcall with my arduino? 
The arduino I use is a: Arduino Uno Wifi Developer Edition

Comment: just do an HTTP call, no such thing as ajax outside of a browser

Answer (score 0):

with Arduino Uno Wifi Developer Edition factory firmware use the Arduino_Uno_WiFi_Dev_Ed_Library from Library Manager. look at RestClient example. (because arduino.org doesn't exist the example doesn't work.)

if you do not like the factory firmware because it is slow and the the library is strange, you can change to WiFi Link or AT firmware with my [Uno WiFi Serial1 library](https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1)